# Can't import library the same way in typescript and javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, commonjs, ecma

I am making my own library that I want to work with both javascript and typescript.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2017",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "./lib",
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/__tests__/*"
    ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "main": "lib/classA.js",
    "types": "lib/classA.d.ts",
    "files": [
      "lib/**/*"
    ],
    "scripts": {
      "build": "tsc"
    }
  }
/*
.
.
.
*/
```

**classAInterfaces.ts**

```
export interface IClassA<T> {
  size(): number;
  /*
  .
  .
  .
  */
}
```

**classA.ts**

```
import { IClassA } from './classAInterfaces';

export default class ClassA<T> implements IClassA<T> {
  constructor() {
      // ...
  }

  size() {
      // ...
  }
  /*
  .
  .
  .
   */
}
```

It gets compiled to:

**classA.d.ts**

```
import { IClassA } from './ClassAInterfaces';
export default class ClassA<T> implements IClassA<T> {
    constructor();
    size(): number;
}
```

**classA.js**

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
class ClassA {
    constructor(options) {
    // ...
    }
    size() {
     // ...
    }
}
exports.default = ClassA;
```

**classAInterfaces.d.ts**

```
export interface IClassA<T> {
    size(): number;
/*
.
.
.
*/
}
```

**classAInterfaces.js**

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

Now, when I want to use it in my projects, I use it in typescript projects without any problems (I build this ts projects in nestjs)

**tsconfig.build.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "dist", "**/*spec.ts"]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "scripts": {
      "build": "nest build",
      "start": "nest start",
    }
    /*
    .
    .
    .
    */
  }
```

**main.ts**

```
import ClassA from 'class-a';

async function main() {
  console.log('--------------------------------', ClassA);
  const q = new ClassA<number>();
  console.log('---------', q.size());
}
main();
```

And it works as expected, prints:

```
-------------------------------- [class ClassA]
--------- 0
```

But, when I try to use it in javascript project

**package.json**

```
{
    "type": "module",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "start": "node ./index.js"
    }
    /*
    .
    .
    .
    */
  }
```

**index.js**

```
import ClassA from 'class-a'


console.log('--------------------------------', ClassA);
const q = new ClassA();
console.log('---------', q.size());
```

I get following output:

```
-------------------------------- { default: [class ClassA] }
file:///C:/Users/win/Desktop/projects/tesst%20library/index.js:5
const q = new ClassA();
          ^

TypeError: ClassA is not a constructor
```

I am able to use it with

```
const q = new ClassA.default();
```

but I don't like it, I would like to use it same way as in typescript.

The only solution I came up with is changing **classA.ts** export:

```
import { IClassA } from './classAInterfaces';

class ClassA<T> implements IClassA<T> {
  constructor() {
    // ...
  }

  size() {
   // ..
  }
}
export = ClassA;
```

which then changes **classA.js** to

```
"use strict";
class ClassA {
    constructor(options) {
    // ...    
    }
    size() {
    // ...
    }
}
module.exports = ClassA;
```

and **classA.d.ts** to:

```
import { IClassA } from './ClassAInterfaces';
declare class ClassA<T> implements IClassA<T> {
    constructor();
    size(): number;
}
export = ClassA;
```

that changes export for classA.js to CommonJS like export. The problem with that solution is that my typescript project then doesn't recognise my library anymore (main.ts prints "-------------------------------- undefined" for first line)

Comment: You've transpiled your typescript to a commonjs module. If you want to use that in a JS `type: module` project, you still need to [import it like a commonjs module](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_import_statements). If you want to import an es module, change your typescript compiler settings to output an es module and change the package.json of the `class-a` package to reflect that. Nodejs doesn't care about `__esModule` - only scripts that are built by transpilers (babel, tsc) do.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you can just add ".js" to the end of the import statement to get things working:

```
import * as whatever from 'file.js';
```

Do this for all of your `.ts` imports, and things should work. Even though the extension is JS, the TS compiler will treat it as the TS file with the same name, then when it comes time to compile, the JS will be importing files correctly.